# Redirecting www.sample.com/index.html to www.sample.com to avoid duplication

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

If I redirect “/index.html” to “/”, will this allow browsing of my website because it no longer has a page titled “/index.html” or does the page it is redirected to (www.sample.com/) still serve as the index (default) page, thus preventing the directories from being exposed? The web server won't let you browse through directories if you have an index page, but does the redirection still maintain the index page, but just not show it in the URL?

I want to know before I make this change rather than just experimenting. I just have one domain on the server and was going to use one of the following scripts in my .htaccess file as suggested by others:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.html$ http://www.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas or comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the index.html to index.php, and just redirect it to www.sample.com

Answer (score 0):

Option `Indexes` in apache is responsible for browsing files and directories on the website.
Write `Options -Indexes` to .htaccess and it will forbid such exposing.